# AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'GenericAlias'

Tags: python

Since I'm working on a linux with no admin rights I tried to install external libs in my project folder like this :

projectRoot
---lib
------some libs
---src
------my project sources

I then updated the PYTHONPATH with `{path to the root}/lib:{path to the root}/src`
Everything seems to be working and I can import my libs fine but this error happened :

```
AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'GenericAlias'
```

I know this can be solved by `from types import GenericAlias` but this error occurs within a lib module, not mine. More specifically when I import urllib.parse.
So what do I do here? 
I work on a remote computer and I only have access to a bash but if needed I can provide additionnal informations.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I missed some libs in my project folder and python tried to find them in another python version... That's why.
I put all the required libs in may project and now it works.